# Differential RC filter

Tags: filter, differential, input, instrumentation-amplifier, passive-filter

I sometimes see differential filters like this:
[image]

And sometimes this :
[image]

Basically sometimes there are 3 caps (2 going to ground on each input), sometimes I only see 1 cap ( 1 differential cap, none going to ground).

Which way is the correct way to do the input filter? What happens when you only use 1 cap instead of 3? Does it matter? When does it matter? What's the advantage of using 3 caps? Meow?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". If you expect a lot of common mode noise, you want to filter the common mode noise, so the capacitors to ground are useful.

However, if you use **just** capacitors to ground, any mismatch in the RC values between the inputs will lead to a degradation of CMRR (common mode rejection ratio) near the cutoff frequency.

Hence, using a differential capacitor 10x the size of the common mode filter capacitors means that is less of an issue.